# Hibernate a MacBook

Tags: hibernate, macbook-pro

I have a 12" MacBook and I can successfully hibernate it using `pmset` (I know for sure it's really hibernating because waking up the laptop shows a progress bar during the resume process).

Unfortunately, `sudo pmset -a lidwake 0` doesn't prevent the laptop from waking on lid open: seems like the setting is completely ignored.

Is there a way to force a complete power down after hibernation?

Comment: I'm not sure there's a valid transition from hibernation to shut down that doesn't involve waking up (i.e. exit hibernation) followed by shut down which tends to point to just shut down if that's the end state you want. Maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: I would like to have my laptop completely powered down while hibernated, as Windows does.

Comment: Because battery life? Because security? Because ... ? (depending on which - you might have options. The clear option is power off when you want it off since hibernate and sleep aren't power off in Apple's firmware and OS design.)

Comment: Because of accidental overheating while in a bag (happened lots of times in the past, and not just to me, unfortunately  ;-)  ) and I need hibernation because it freezes my session (ropen windows on reboot it's not a very reliable option since there are apps, not designed by Apple, that don't follow their guidelines for what concerns resuming a session)

Comment: Got it - those are the worst. No battery, seems to be running hotter than you feel is OK for the hardware. I wonder if hibernate uses more CPU/heat than a simple sleep/wake would in those cases where you have it cycling awake and closed repeatedly in a closed bag.